# Yii Framework 2.0 GridView and data from the join table

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have two database tables 'user' and 'role'. I used Yii framework 2.0 Gii to create CRUD with User model and UserSearch model. By default, Gii uses GridView::widget for the index page for the 'user' model.

In the search($params) method inside of the UserSearch model, I used the following code to join the above tables together

```
$query = User::find()->with('role');
```

Everything works fine with the query.

By default Gii does not include the data from the joined table 'role' in the GridView::widget inside of the views/user/index.php page. With the join query above I could retrieve data from both tables. In the views/user/index.php page I have injected the GridView::widget with the following code so that it also includes the data and column names from the joined table (role).

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'userid',
        'username',
        'role.role_name',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Everything works fine with the role data 'role_name included in the GridView::widget. But the problem is that there is no search box for the role_name. The GridView::widget creates search box for the User properties only. Is there any way to add search box for the properties of the joined table 'role' because I also  would like to search through 'role_name' as well as through other properties of the User model.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$columns-detail
here yii2 defined the column name inside a array with in the main column array. I never used this before. Hope this might help

Comment: I have read that documentation. I know how to add custom columns to the detault Gridview widget, the custom columns of the joined table for example. But the problem is that there is no search box for the custom columns. The default columns of the Gridview have the search box on the header as well.

Comment: have you tried to show only single column (role_name)

Comment: Yes I did and the column 'role_name' is also added to the Gridview. But there is no searchbox on top of that column.

Comment: @O Connor Added the yii2 filter answer.Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: @O Connor - did you get any answer for this....I am facing the same problem ....my search box is not visible while using any other table column in gridview

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

In your UserSearch model add

```
UserSearch extends ...
{
    public $roleFilterInputName; //the name of the filter search input

    //important
    function rules()
    {
        //add roleFilterInputName as safe
        return [
            [['xxx', 'roleFilterInputName'], 'safe'], //!!!!
        ];
    }
}
```

in your grid:

```
'columns':
[
    //...
    [
    'attribute' => 'roleFilterInputName',
    'value' => 'role.role_name'
    ],
    //...
]
```

in UserSearch::search()

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'role.role_name', $this->roleFilterInputName])
```

But I guess you'll have to use 'joinWith' instead of 'with'.

Answer (score 1):

1. Inside CGridView add below code. It will enable filter with dropDownList.

   ```
      [
           'attribute' => 'act_role_id',
           'label' => 'Actor Role',
           'value' => 'actRole.role_name',
           'filter' => yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\ActorRole::find()->orderBy('role_name')->asArray()->all(),'act_role_id','role_name')
       ],
   ```

CGridView code Snippet is as below:

```
   <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'userid',
        'username',
        [
            'attribute' => 'act_role_id',
            'label' => 'Actor Role',
            'value' => 'actRole.role_name',
            'filter' => yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\ActorRole::find()->orderBy('role_name')->asArray()->all(),'act_role_id','role_name')
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your code is for Yii 1 and I am using Yii 2.0. I have tried to convert your Yii 1 code sample into Yii 2 code, but no luck. Can you show me how to do that in Yii 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'userid',
        'username',

        //'role.role_name',
        ['attribute' => 'role', 'value' => 'role.role_name'],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I just have tried it in my code, so I'm not sure if this works also with your code. But if so, I don't know why it has to be defined this way.

I guess the answer of rajesh ujade also includes this definition, however, for Yii 1.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me 
Table = Lead  (id , year_id)
Table = Year  (id, text)

Added text in lead (index.php)
Year::find()->all()  = This code pull all value from table/ all years.

```
            [
            'attribute'=> 'year_id',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value' => 'year.value',
            'label' => 'Year',
            'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'year', yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(Year::find()->all(), 'year_id', 'value'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'prompt' => '---']),

        ],
```

Also it shows dropdown as well sorting.

[image Showing Dropdown in Grdiview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IZ9h.png)

Answer (score 0):

@Ekonoval is going in right way.

Just add following in serch function of UserSearch:

After initializing ActiveDataProvider object like this:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 5,
    ],
]);

$dataProvider->sort->attributes['roleFilterInputName'] = [
    'asc' => ['role.role_name' => SORT_ASC],
    'desc' => ['role.role_name' => SORT_DESC]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may write query in your UserSearch model like

```
if($this->role)
{
   $query->join('LEFT JOIN','role','role.user_id =   user.id')->andFilterWhere(['role.item_name' => $this->role]);
}
```